# Async socket confusion

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

My socket client does not appear to be handling situations where the buffer is full and there is more data to be received.

Here is my on receive method, simple version:

```
private void Recieve()
{
    this._clientSocket.BeginReceive(this._buffer, 0, this._buffer.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), this._clientSocket);
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Socket clientSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
    int bytesRead = clientSocket.EndReceive(result);
    this.Recieve();
    string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this._buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(this.HandleDataReceived), data);
}
```

This doesn't handle situations where there is more data to be received at all. So then I tried this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx):

```
private string receivedString = string.Empty;
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Socket clientSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
    int bytesRead = clientSocket.EndReceive(result);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        receivedString += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this._buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        this.Recieve();
    }
    else
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(this.HandleDataReceived), this.receivedString);
        this.receivedString = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

But the problem i'm having with this is that when bytesRead > 0 and I call BeginReceive again I do not get another callback. Did I make some kind of mistake ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code, you have a race condition. Consider:

```
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Socket clientSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
    int bytesRead = clientSocket.EndReceive(result);
    this.Recieve();
    string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this._buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(this.HandleDataReceived), data);
}
```

You call `Receive` again, which could overwrite `buffer` before you send the data to your `HandleDataReceived` method. I think you want to move that Receive call to *after* you've converted the data:

```
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Socket clientSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
    int bytesRead = clientSocket.EndReceive(result);
    string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this._buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(this.HandleDataReceived), data);
    this.Recieve();
}
```

In the second case, you never read 0 bytes because the socket is waiting for data. If there is no data, [Socket.Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xtz6a5.aspx) will block until there is data available, or until the connection is closed. `BeginReceive` is waiting for data.

Comment: Hi Jim. Thanks for the heads up re. the race condition. I will make that change. Re. your second point, I don't quite understand. Should I be using Socket.Receive instead of BeginReceive ? In the msdn link they are using BeginReceive .. thanks!

Comment: @Sherlock: In the example code you linked, the server and client are set up to send and receive a single message pair. The client waits for the sender's message, then sends one back and exits. The server doesn't get the client's message until the client closes the socket.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, however i'm still very confused. I've seen a lot of examples that work in the same way and while I understand what you're saying about it waiting to receive more data, I don't understand how to properly handle situations where there is more data to receive. Any more advice or examples you could provide is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Sherlock: My code shown above should handle the situation where there is more data to receive. The only problem I saw in your code was that race condition. Does the modified code not work?

Comment: Hi Jim - In the code above how can I tell if there is more data to receive, or if the  full message has been received ? Would I need to use some kind of exit char, or parse the JSON to check for the closing "}" ?

Comment: @Sherlock: With a network stream there is no way in general to tell if more data is forthcoming. So your message format has to either tell you how much data there is, or it has to have a message delimiter (like the `}` character you mentioned).